# How to specify -d flag with device ID using DAP

Tags: flutter, dart, neovim

When i run dap continue, debugger starts but soon after it closes itself after asking to specify device.

So i was wondering what is best solution to this and can i specify -d flag and maybe hardcode chrome?

Here is my code so far:

[link to flutter tools](https://github.com/akinsho/flutter-tools.nvim)

```
return {
        "akinsho/flutter-tools.nvim",
        dependencies = { "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim", "stevearc/dressing.nvim" },
        lazy = false,
        config = function()
            local fltools = require("flutter-tools")
            fltools.setup({
                lsp = {
                    settings = {
                        linelength = vim.o.textwidth,
                    }
               },
                debugger = {
                    enabled = true,
                    run_via_dap = true,
                    register_configurations = function(_)
                        local dap = require("dap")
   
                        dap.adapters.dart = {
                            type = "executable",
                            command = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/mason/bin/dart-debug-adapter",
                            args = { "flutter" }
                        }
   
                        dap.configurations.dart = {
                            {
                                type = "dart",
                                request = "launch",
                                name = "launch flutter",
                                dartsdkpath = '/users/herculepoirot/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/',
                                fluttersdkpath = "/users/herculepoirot/flutter",
                                program = "${workspacefolder}/lib/main_dev.dart",
                                cwd = "${workspacefolder}",
                                device = "chrome",
                            }
                        }
                    end,
                },
   
            })
   
            fltools.setup_project({
               {
                    name = 'web',
                    device = 'chrome',                    
                    target = "lib/main_dev.dart",
                    flutter_mode = "debug",
                },
                {
                    name = 'mac',
                    device = 'mac',
                    target = "lib/main_dev.dart",
                    flutter_mode = "debug",
                }
            })
        end
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `toolArgs = {"-d","chrome"}` in dap.configuration.dart table.

```
dap.configurations.dart = {
   {
      type = "dart",
      request = "launch",
      name = "launch flutter",
      dartsdkpath = '/users/herculepoirot/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/',
      fluttersdkpath = "/users/herculepoirot/flutter",
      program = "${workspacefolder}/lib/main_dev.dart",
      cwd = "${workspacefolder}",
      device = "chrome",
      toolArgs = {"-d","chrome"}
   }
}
```

Comment: Before i added toolArgs dap would stop bcs device was not specified. Now after using your solution im getting Error spawn /bin/sh ENOENT. I think there is something wrong with my config.  Do you have flutter configured with dap if so can you share your config?

Comment: Here it is.
https://github.com/sharmashashi/nvim-pde/blob/main/dapconfig.lua